# portaudio only taking one sample?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, debugging, portaudio

I am currently working with portaudio with an application that records, and I seem to have some issues collecting the samples. From what I can see is only one sample being stored, and the callback is only being called once, and that is it, even though the variable `NUM_OF_SECONDS` is set to 30 seconds.

I currently running out of ideas of what I can test, and how I can debug this, so I've come here, any suggestions to how I can debug my problem?

Here is the code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <record.h>

int main()
{
    record  somethis;
    somethis.start_record();
    return 0;
}
```

record.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream> // Functionality: COUT
#include "portaudio.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>  //Functionality: Sleep
#include <thread>   //Functionality: Sleep
#include <algorithm> //Functionality: fill_n
#define SAMPLE_RATE (44100)

typedef float SAMPLE;

#define NUM_SECONDS 30
#define NUM_CHANNELS  2
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE 0.0f
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (512)
#define TRUE (1==1)
#define FALSE (!TRUE)
#define WRITE_TO_FILE   TRUE


typedef struct
{
    int     frameIndex;
    int     maxFrameindex;
    SAMPLE  *recordedSamples;
}
paTestData;

class record {
public:
    record();
    void start_record();
private:
    PaStreamParameters  inputParameters,
                        outputParameters;
    PaStream*           stream;
    PaError             err = paNoError;
    paTestData          data;
    int                 totalFrames;
    int                 numSamples;
    int                 numBytes;
    SAMPLE              max, val;
    double              average;
    int recordCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                       unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                       const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                       PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData);

    static int recordCallbackSub(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                       unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
                       PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
    {
        auto pThis = reinterpret_cast<record*>(userData);  // get back the this pointer.
        return pThis->recordCallback( inputBuffer, outputBuffer,framesPerBuffer, timeInfo,statusFlags, nullptr);

    }
};
```

record.cpp

```
#include "record.h"


record::record()
{
    std::cout << "Record object made" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Portaudio Version: " << Pa_GetVersion() << std::endl;
    this->data.maxFrameindex = this->totalFrames = NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE;
    this->data.frameIndex = 0;
    this->numSamples = this->totalFrames * NUM_CHANNELS;
    numBytes = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    this->data.recordedSamples = new SAMPLE[numSamples]; /* From now on, recordedSamples is initialised. */
    if( this->data.recordedSamples == NULL )
    {
        std::cout << "Could not allocate record array" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<numSamples; i++ )
    {
        this->data.recordedSamples[i] = 0;

    }

    int err = Pa_Initialize();

    if( err == paNoError )
    {
        std::cout << "No error in init" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PortAudio init: "<< Pa_GetErrorText( err ) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
       printf(  "PortAudio error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
       exit(1);
    }

    this->inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice(); /* default input device */


    if (this->inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        std::cout << "Error: No default input device" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    this->inputParameters.channelCount = 1;                    /* stereo input */
    this->inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    this->inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( this->inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
    this->inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    std::cout << "Device name: "  <<Pa_GetDeviceInfo(this->inputParameters.device)->name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max inputChannels: "  <<Pa_GetDeviceInfo(this->inputParameters.device)->maxInputChannels << std::endl;

}

int record::recordCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    std::cout << "Callback called" << std::endl;
    this->data = (paTestData&) userData;
    const SAMPLE *rptr = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    SAMPLE *wptr = &this->data.recordedSamples[this->data.frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    long framesToCalc;
    long i;
    int finished;
    unsigned long framesLeft = this->data.maxFrameindex - this->data.frameIndex;

    (void) outputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    //(void) userData;

    if( framesLeft < framesPerBuffer )
    {
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    }
    else
    {
        framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    }

    if( inputBuffer == NULL )
    {
        for(int i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* left */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* right */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* left */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS == 2 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* right */
        }
    }
    this->data.frameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return finished;
}

void record::start_record()
{

    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &this->stream,
              &this->inputParameters,
              NULL,                  /* &outputParameters, */
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              &record::recordCallbackSub,
              this );
    if( err != paNoError )
    {
        std::cout << "Something wrong  - open_stream check" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PortAudio error: "<< Pa_GetErrorText( err ) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    this->err = Pa_StartStream( this->stream );

    if( err != paNoError )
    {
        std::cout << "Something wrong in stream check" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PortAudio error: "<< Pa_GetErrorText( err ) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "Waiting for playback to finish" << std::endl;

    while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive( stream ) ) == 1 )
    {
        Pa_Sleep(1000);
        printf("index = %d\n", this->data.frameIndex ); fflush(stdout);

    }
    if( err < 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "error check with isStreamActive - something wrong" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PortAudio error: "<< Pa_GetErrorText( err ) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError )
    {
        std::cout << "error check with close_stream- something wrong" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PortAudio error: "<< Pa_GetErrorText( err ) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "Number of entries: " <<  sizeof(this->data.recordedSamples)/sizeof(this->data.recordedSamples[0]) << std::endl;

    /* Measure maximum peak amplitude. */
    max = 0;
    average = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<numSamples; i++ )
    {

        val = this->data.recordedSamples[i];
        std::cout << "i: " << i << " : "<< val << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

        if( val < 0 ) val = -val; /* ABS */
        if( val > max )
        {
            max = val;
        }
        average += val;
    }

    average = average / (double)numSamples;

    std::cout<<"sample max amplitude = " << max << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"sample average = " <<  average << std::endl;

    if (WRITE_TO_FILE)
    {
        FILE  *fid;
        fid = fopen("recorded.wav", "wb");
        if( fid == NULL )
        {
            printf("Could not open file.");
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite( data.recordedSamples, NUM_CHANNELS * sizeof(SAMPLE), totalFrames, fid );
            fclose( fid );
            printf("Wrote data to 'recorded.raw'\n");
        }
    }



    std::cout << "Everythin done!" << std::endl;



}
```

Update:

I've from some debugging notices that the callback is only being called once, and after it returns, becomes the stream inactive, hence making the it impossible to make calls to the callback function. Why does the stream become inactive?

Comment: please make the question answerable only with information contained within. External links shouldn't be required to visit in order to answer the question

Comment: what language are you writing in? Is it `C` or `C++`. Please pick one.

Comment: I added the code and changed the tags @bolov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first callback

```
static int recordCallbackSub(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                   unsigned long framesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
                   PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    auto pThis = reinterpret_cast<record*>(userData);  // get back the this pointer.
    return pThis->recordCallback( inputBuffer, outputBuffer,framesPerBuffer, timeInfo,statusFlags, nullptr);

}
```

calls your second callback

```
int record::recordCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void *userData)
{
    std::cout << "Callback called" << std::endl;
    this->data = (paTestData&) userData;

    ....
}
```

with the `userData` parameter set to `nullptr`. You then cast the `nullptr` into a `paTestData&` and set your `data` member variable to the result, which I suspect you didn't intend to do.

Delete the `this->data = (paTestData&) userData;` line.

Comment: It seems to have fixed it.. I was using the paex_record.c example script portaudio had provided. I was/still am a bit unsure on what the userData actually does?

Comment: The userData parameter is a fairly common feature of C APIs like Port Audio and the purpose of it is to let you pass arbitrary, user defined information to a callback. You've done this yourself where you pass a pointer to a class to your `recordCallbackSub` function - allowing you to get from a static function to a member function. Without a `void *userData` parameter this simply wouldn't be possible.

The paex_record.c example uses this mechanism to pass a data struct into the callback, but since you're already inside your class you can just use member variables directly instead.